# PrepareResourceRules task failed error while building .NET MAUI app in VS for Mac

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac

I'm able to build my .NET MAUI app on my Windows 11 machine using VS 2022 17.4.4 but when I try to build it on a Mac using VS 2022 17.4.3 (Build 21), it fails with the following error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.1.1481/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3):
> Error MSB4018: The "PrepareResourceRules" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path
> '/Users/user231632/Documents/MyAppFolder/MyApp/bin/Release/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist'.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try to create a new project on Mac and build it successfully? Can the build project succeed if the Mac ([pair to Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-7.0)) is connected remotely on Windows?

Comment: If I create a new project, it builds fine. What confuses me is that I manually remove `bin` and `obj` folders to make sure there's no residue from previous builds, etc. I still get it in that project but as I mentioned, if I start a fresh new project, it works fine. What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried remotely connecting to Mac (pair to Mac) on Windows to build this project successfully?

Comment: Did you find any solution?